# How to Convert int to RxInt in Dart || Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, integer

Future<RxInt> sharePreff() async {

RxInt i = 0.obs;

SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

```
int? n = preferences.getInt("counter");
i = n as RxInt;

return i;
```

}

- `Does not convert from int to RxInt`
- how is possible  //  type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'RxInt' in type cast  // error

  Future<RxInt> sharePrefff() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  RxInt? n = 0.obs;
  n = preferences.getInt("counter") as RxInt?;

  i = n!;

  return i;
  }
- I was try but it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

or maybe you could simply sum the `int` value to `RxInt`:

```
//...
 int? n = preferences.getInt("counter");
 i.value = i.value + n;

 return i;
}
```

thus will return the same `RxInt` but summed with the int you get from your local device storage.